# Augmented Dickey Fuller test, determining the number of lags used

Tags: unit-root, lags, augmented-dickey-fuller, information-criteria

In a paper by Mark P. Taylor he conducts ADF tests on exchange rates and he describes the determination of lag number with "The number of lagged dependents that we need to include to induce residual whiteness". Does this mean that he determines the number of lags that are considered in the ADF test depending on which number of lags makes the residual homoscedastic? If so, could somebody shed some light on why this is a reasonable idea?

Generally, I would pick the lag length which provides the minimal information criteria.

Comment: Hi: The way I think of it is,  if you don't have white residuals ( which I assume means independdent residuals that resemble normality )  after estimation, then that means that more lags needed to be included because there is still "predictability" that hasn't been sucked out by the coefficients. So, by including more lags, you can improve the model which means the coefficients are more reliable. The whole thing about the ADF test is that you want reliable coefficient estimates and, the better the model, the more reliable the coefficients are.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Interesting view, how would you elaborate the whiteness of the residuals? White test after estimation?

Comment: Further, would you suggest then that picking a lag length that results in whitness of residuals rather than a lag length that results in the smallest information criteria?

Comment: Hi: For your first comment, I think the box-leung test tests for no correlation between residuals.  I'm not familar with white's test but there are many variants of box-leung so maybe white is one of those ?

Comment: Hi: For your second comment, the  AIC focuses more on the minimization of likelihood ( with a penality for number of parameters ) rather than whiteness of residuals so that's why I say better to go with whiteness. Recall that, in an ADF test, you're really just interested in whether the first coefficient is 1.0 so getting that first coefficient correct is more important than getting the overall model correct. ADF is really just a diagnostic. You're not really building a model. It's fuzzy to me for sure because it's been a good while. I remember Hamilton and Enders being good for this topic.